# Sphinx fails to reindex on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, reindex

I have a Rails app using the following:
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Thinking Sphinx 4.4.1
Flying Sphinx 1.2.0

Currently I am successfully able to reindex (rake ts:rebuild) on development.  When I do so, I see it generate development.sphinx.conf.  When I push this to staging on heroku, I run the same command and get:

```
I, [2021-05-26T22:25:17.260156 #4]  INFO -- : [RailsAutoscale] Preparing middleware
D, [2021-05-26T22:25:17.404021 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
searchd is not currently running.
D, [2021-05-26T22:25:17.988676 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
Generating configuration to /app/config/staging.sphinx.conf
Generating configuration to /app/config/staging.sphinx.conf
sh: 1: indexer: not found

The Sphinx indexing command failed:
  Command: indexer --config "/app/config/staging.sphinx.conf" --all
  Status:  127
  Output:  See above

There may be more information about the failure in /app/log/staging.searchd.log.
```

I looked for the log, but I cannot find it.  What I do know is that the staging config file is not being generated.  If anyone has any clues to point me towards fixing this, I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be in a situation where you're using older gems than the documentation expects. For flying-sphinx v1.x, you need to use the `flying-sphinx` executable instead of the `ts:`-prefixed rake tasks: `heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx rebuild`.

If you upgrade to flying-sphinx v2.x, then you'll be able to use the ts rake tasks on Heroku as well as locally. (Yes, this would have been the ideal behaviour from the get-go, but better late than never!)

Comment: This is a great clue!  Gonna try to see if that is the issue.  I appreciate it.